# Intersection of a ListPlot3D surface with a plane

Tags: fitting, interpolation

I'm trying to use Mathematica to analyze some physics data from an experiment, more precisely, I have to fit a 2D data series with a one dimension function.

At the moment I'm able to load and plot correctly all the data, using the following command:

```
ListPlot3D[Img3, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Orange, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
     MaxPlotPoints -> 150]
```

Where `Img3` is a list with about 523000 `{x, y, z}` points. I obtain the following 3-D plot:

[image: First view of the plot]
[image: Another view of the plot]

I would like to make a section of the plotted surface with a vertical plane (and I will have to adjust the vertical plane `x,y` direction to obtain a good cross intersection with the little "waves" on the top of the surface), and fit the profile of the intersection with a gaussian function + another function (this 3Dplot is the intensity profile of two interfering laser beams).

Is that possible?
I've looked around a lot to search how to do it, but I didn't find anything that matches with my needs, right now I'm not able to get the profile of the intersection of this `ListPlot3D` surface with a plane.
(I will manage by my own to fit the profile)

Answer (score 5):

I guess what you are looking for can be easily achieved (and adjusted) with the [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) option. Let me give an example using `Plot3D`. It should work similarly with `ListPlot3D`:

```
 Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Sin[10 x + 0.1 y]^2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotPoints -> 25,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z < height],
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]
  ],
 {{height, 1}, 0, 1}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Edit

@MarcoB just pointed out that you are not interested in a graphics but the points of your cross section. One pretty easy way to get started is to forget the `ListPlot3D` and just concentrate on what you want:

A contour of your function in a certain height `z`. So let's do this instead and extract the points of those contours. I'm using the exact same function and it should work for you too when you use `ListContourPlot`:

```
gr = ContourPlot[
  Sin[10 x + 0.1 y]^2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] - .3 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,
    2}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we use the fact that those closed contours are stored as separate point list. The variable `section` will be a list of paths, where each path is a list of 2d points:

```
sections = Cases[Normal[gr], Line[pts__] :> pts, Infinity];
ListLinePlot[sections]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Would it be possible to extract the numerical values corresponding to those boundaries from the OP's `ListPlot3D` or from the data itself, however? My understanding of the question was that the OP needed to extract the shape of those profiles to be able to fit them to his expression.

Comment: @MarcoB I see. Finding and tracing the contours so that you get a (interpolating) function or a path of points is a different story. It can be done by extracting the points from a contour plot, but I'm not sure I would rely on this for a scientific project.

Comment: Looks great! Thank you for following up on this point. As for the robustness of this approach when fed experimental data, I guess that will be for the OP to investigate. (+1, of course)

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that he wanted to slice the surface with a plane perpendicular to the $x$-$y$ plane, so I thought he could form an `InterpolatingFunction[]` from his data, and then maybe apply that to the result of `RotationMatrix[θ].({x, y} - pt)` for some value of `θ` and `pt`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. If this is the case then the problem is of course much easier.

Comment: My intention is exactly what @Guesswhoitis. pointed out.

My issue is that I can't find how to make an intersection of the `ListPlot3D` surface with an _x-y_ plane, and get a list with the points in the intersection to subsequently fit with my functions (I found examples for intersection of a parametric function or a `Plot3D`, but no one for a `ListPlot3D`)

Comment: @Mirko, some distinctions first: if you want to slice with the $x$-$y$ plane, then that is exactly what halirutan did. What you actually want is to slice with planes parallel to the $z$-axis. :) Having gotten that out of the way, I sketched a possible solution in my previous comment.