# Plot a function on a restricted domain

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a function $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ restricted to a domain $D \subset \mathbb R^n$. The domain $D$ is usually specified as the set of zeros for a set of polynomial equations (i.e. an algebraic variety). For example consider the function $f(x,y) = x^{39}y^{63}$ 
on the ellipse $D := \left\{(x,y)\ \ \big|\ x^2+xy+y^2-1=0\right\}$. How would I plot this for example in *Mathematica*? (I am on version 7.0.)

Comment: You could add an option:RegionFunction->(...)

Comment: Great! That was easy! Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem to work:

    Plot3D[x^39*y^63, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 + x*y == 1]]

Comment: And also -- read this [`(83692)`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83692/intersection-of-a-listplot3d-surface-with-a-plane)

Comment: That's because the 'region' you're plotting in is actually just an infinitesimally thin line. Try `Plot3D[x^39*y^63, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 + x*y <=1&&x^2 + y^2 + x*y >0.9],PlotRange->All]`. It isn't exactly what you want, but it'll show you what the problem is. I think you'd be better off with a different representation of your problem. ParametricPlot3D might work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the closest way I can imagine to get what you were originally trying to get, though it still may not be the best way to plot what you care about.

First get a parametric representation of y in terms of x.

```
y[x_]=y/.Solve[x^2 + x*y + y^2 == 1, y,Reals];
```

Then make a parametric plot over the full range of x. I kept the two regions defined by the solution separate so you can see what's going on.

```
  ParametricPlot3D[{
     {x,Max@y[x],x^39*(Max@y[x])^63},
     {x,Min@y[x],x^39*(Min@y[x])^63}
     }
    ,{x,-Sqrt[2],Sqrt[2]},PlotRange->All,BoxRatios->1]
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: You probably want to use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` to avoid evaluating `Solve` repeatedly. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Constructing a trigonometric parametrization of the ellipse ought to make for a neater plot. :)

Comment: Or `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Thread[{x, y[x], x^39*y[x]^63}]], {x, -Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> 1]`